# getting Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/config in Netbeans'

Tags: java, netbeans, connection, pool

I've searched through similar questions and didn't find a solution that worked for me. I'm running following in Netbeans > servlet:

```
public Connection getConnection()
{
    Connection result = null;
    BasicDataSource dataSource = getDataSource();
    try {
        result = dataSource.getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ConnectionPool.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    catch (Throwable e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

It works fine when executed in a Java project. Then I added this project's jar as a library to a servlet project in Netbeans - it throws exception:

"java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/config'"

It looks like this "class ''" thing should point to a class name but where do I get it?

Answer (score 0):

fixed that. had to put drivers into glassfish/lib directory